# Pagination of RSS2 feed

Tags: pagination, rss

How to have pagination of RSS2 feed ?

My current RSS link is similar to :

```
http://www.example.com/?feed=rss2
```

I tried:

```
http://www.example.com/?feed=rss2&page=2
```

But WordPress still returns me with same set of result, given that I set 10 posts per page in

> Dashboard > Settings > Reading > Syndication feeds show the most recent

(of course I have more than 10 posts)

Comment: Yyyy... And why are you trying to add pagination to rss? I don't think that RSS readers will use this...

Comment: but my mobile App will use this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use `paged` not `page` in the request and it should work.

You can find more information about WordPress pagination paged parameter [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query).

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the page load from `WP-Admin` > `Settings` > `Reading`:

In *Syndication feeds show the most recent* choose how many items will be in each page of the feed.

And now your feed is pagination-ready. Browse it with:
http://www.example.com/?feed=rss2&paged=1

> **Default Permalink:**
>   **Syntax:** `http://domain/?feed=rss2&paged=#`

For any other permalink, other than Default, [a question of mine is still waiting unanswered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102598/wordpress-permalinks-postname-for-rss2-feed-url). There you will find more syntax about RSS feed.