# Second page of RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed

I have a my default feed url `https://tocanerd.com.br/feed/`, but i set it up to show a **x** number of posts. I'd like to know how to see the other posts in a second page or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can request different pages of an RSS feed by setting the `paged` parameter. (Important: not `page`, but `paged` with an extra `d` at the end!)

> http://www.example.com/feed/?paged=1

A WordPress theme can disable/break this behavior, though.

- WordPress documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination
- Related question: [Pagination of RSS2 feed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108185/pagination-of-rss2-feed)

Answer (score 0):

Feeds don't support paging. You can only set the number of items to include in the feed, but nothing more. Feed readers don't support paging, but most feed readers cache old posts from each feed (depending on the reader).